# Cannot update conda packages after accidentally closed the anaconda prompt while updating packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, command-prompt

Like the title said, I closed the anaconda prompt thinking the update was completed, but it was at the final stage waiting to be completed. Now Every time I enter "conda update --all" the following error message will pop up:

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda update --all
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1213): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'update')
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
    if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 718, in use_only_tar_bz2
    use_only_tar_bz2 = VersionOrder(conda_build.__version__) < VersionOrder("3.18.3")
AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1211, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 238, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
        if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 718, in use_only_tar_bz2
        use_only_tar_bz2 = VersionOrder(conda_build.__version__) < VersionOrder("3.18.3")
    AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'

`$ C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update --all`

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

---

I tried reverting to the previos revision, but it failed. The error message is the following:

```
   (base) C:\Users\User>conda install --revision 163
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1213): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
    if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 718, in use_only_tar_bz2
    use_only_tar_bz2 = VersionOrder(conda_build.__version__) < VersionOrder("3.18.3")
AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1211, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 238, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
        if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 718, in use_only_tar_bz2
        use_only_tar_bz2 = VersionOrder(conda_build.__version__) < VersionOrder("3.18.3")
    AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'

`$ C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install --revision 163`

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

---

Then I tried checking the status of the conda environment by `conda info --envs`, but a new error message also pops up:

(base) C:\Users\User>conda info --envs

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 316, in execute
        info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 132, in get_info_dict
        conda_build_version = conda_build.__version__
    AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'

`$ C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info --envs`


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

I saw there are `KeyError('pkgs_dirs')` and `AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'` in common in these two error messages, so I guess the problem lies in these stuff. But I honestly have no idea how to revert the environment without triggering these issues again. If nothing else works, I might as well uninstall the entire conda stuff again and reinstall it, but doing so means not learning the right way to tackle the problems.

Comment: Can you include the output from `conda config --show`? Maybe also show the `.condarc` file (usually in the user home directory - not sure exactly for Windows).

Comment: @merv Too late I already hard reset everything, though I now have a new issue, which is that when I switch to a new environment I created, Spyder 4.13 won't compile any python files that I run, not even the simplest "hello world.py"